# Change Date Format in SharePoint 2016

Tags: date-time, formatting

I want to change the format of date from `MM-DD-YYYY` to `DD-MM-YYYY` in list, Gantt charts etc. I have tried one option so far but it doesn't work properly which is explain below:

First option: I have change the regional and locale settings in the parent site. It helps to change the general date format such as when the document was created library. But it does not the change the format in Gantt Charts when we assign dates to a particular task.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have a SP16 tenant for me to be able to test, but certainly in SP13 the way to change the date format would be to change the Regional Settings for the Site Collection (/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx).

Site Settings > Regional Settings > Locale > English (United Kingdom)

Comment: Thanks for answering George, but I did the same thing and it changes the format of dates that are created by sharePoint e.g. When you upload a document it shows when the document uploaded and the date is in correct format. <br> It does not change the dates the one I creates e.g. assigning due date in Gantt Chart.

Answer (score 0):

***The first solution***

Just go and change your Regional Settings of your Site Collection, and choose what region would help your needs

You just need to follow these steps:

1. go to Site Settings
2. go to Site Administrations Section → Regional Settings
3. go to Region Section → Locale

[image]

there apply the changes you need.

***The second solution***

go to your column setting, and edit the date format

[image]

Good luck.

> if this answer to your question, please mark it